# Attack on stream cipher that XOR's the output of two LFSRs

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, lfsr

There are two LFSRs of different lengths: LFSR-17 and LFSR-25. LFSR-17 Initially contains a two byte seed, with a 1 injected into the fourth bit, for a total of 17 bits. LFSR-25 operates in the same way.

Of the 40-bit key, 2 bytes is seeded into the first LFSR and 3 bytes into the other. If the outputs of each LFSR were simply XORd to produce the keystream, how could we launch a known plaintext to retrieve the key?

Comment: Hint: assume you know the first (say, 8) octets of the plaintext (and the corresponding ciphertext). Further, temporarily assume that you know the first 2 bytes of the key. How do you find the 3 others without guesswork? Now, if these first 2 bytes of the key are only a guess, how do you check that guess?

Comment: @fgrieu's hint is divide and conquer.

Comment: Alternate idea: could it be that you can use [Berlekamp-Massey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm)?

Answer (score 3):

There is another method named algebraic attack.

- Name each of the keys initial keys by $l_{1i}$ and $l_{2i}$.
- Since the LFSRs are linear and the combining function, x-or, is also linear compute algebraic equations
- Solve them. They construct a linear system of solutions.

Since only 38 bits are keys, you will only need 38-bit output if the if the equations are linearly independent.

if you use the Gaussian elimination method it will have $40^3$ operations.